# Create index if it does not exist with Mongo Reactive

Tags: mongodb, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a requirement to create index when there is not that index. For example, via below code I can filter out index for alternativeLocations.

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps(IncotermLocation.class).getIndexInfo().filter( indexInfo -> indexInfo.getName().equals("alternativeLocations")).
```

If this Flux is empty, then I should create the index, otherwise not. swithIfempty will not work because

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps(IncotermLocation.class).ensureIndex(new Index().named("alternativeLocations").on("unLocationCodes", Sort.Direction.ASC))
```

will only return `Mono<String>` which is different with `Mono<IndexInfo>`.

How can I use reactive to realize the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are many ways, for example, you could just add `.map()` operation before filter (or even after, it does not really matter in this case) to extract the name of index as you're dealing with index names.

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps(IncotermLocation.class).getIndexInfo()
        .map(indexInfo -> indexInfo.getName())
        .filter(indexName -> indexName.equals("alternativeLocations"))
        .switchIfEmpty(reactiveMongoTemplate.indexOps(IncotermLocation.class)
                .ensureIndex(new Index().named("alternativeLocations").on("unLocationCodes", Sort.Direction.ASC))
        );
```